# Selenium Python After pressing the button,a new window opens,I can't press the keys there

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to python
https://prnt.sc/26nlk3q
I press the button on the site, then this window appears in which you need to click to confirm
I tried this

`driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])`

And This

`alert = browser.switch_to.alert`

`alert.accept()`

but its not working for me

I can show you how it looks in the browser, if necessary

This window has a separate html code, I do not understand how to access it

Comment: Please don't use external links. In your case my browser blocks your link, because it identifies it as spam.
Add everything that's necessary to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the query is related to switching tabs. Try this:

> driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

In `driver.window_handles[]` method, you are required to specify the index of the tab in `[]` `[0]` is the first tab, `[1]` is the second tab, and so on. I think this should clear the doubt.